# grab variable from url for routing

Tags: cakephp

I want to grab a variable from an url for redirects in my cakephp app ie

```
example.com/value -> example.com/controller/this:value
```

obviously, the rest of the routing should remain intact. Is this possible with routing in cakephp?

Im using cakephp 1.3

I want to check the URL first against a field in a database table, if it doesnt exist, then pass it through routing. I'm assuming this will be in the beforeFilter of the app controller.

Comment: can you be a little bit more precise? also, you should state your exact cake version.

Comment: ive added more detail and my version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, you cannot access the database prior to the routes.php.

Just as you assumed, the alternative would be to build your logic into the `beforeFilter` of the `AppController`, which should be fine.

Probably something you'll want to cache though, since it will hit on EVERY page load.